# Weird control-d behavior

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, cat

I can use `cat` as a very simple text editor by doing `cat > foo.txt`.
If I then type:

```
bar
baz
```

and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it now looks like this:

```
$ cat > foo.txt
bar
baz^D
```

with the cursor at the `^`. If I then press it once more the file will get saved. However if I press anything (okay maybe not anything, but mostly anything) else, I just continue to edit the file.

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. It has to do with `^D` really does: it just stops the current `read(2)` call.

If the program does `int rdbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);` and you press `^D` inbetween, `read()` returns with the currently read bytes in the buffer, returning their number. The same happens on line termination; the `\n` at the end is always delivered.

So only a `^D` at the start of a line or after another `^D` has the desired effect of having `read()` return `0`, signalizing EOF.

Comment: It depends on what you define a *line* to be (with or without a trailing `\n`.. but it is possible to just press `^D` twice in succession, and cause an EOF condition without generating a final newline char (as pressing Enter before the `^D`would do).

Comment: Your are right, I forgot to mention that: Start of line and "just pressed ^D" are the two situations where the buffer is empty, so ^D will have `read()` return `0`, indicating EOF.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is normal behavior.  A single Control-D normally only breaks out if it's the beginning of the line.  This exits with one Control-D:

```
$ cat > foo.txt
bar
baz
^D
```

Comment: Control-D twice at the end of a line does break out, without a trailing newline char...

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I didn't mean to imply otherwise.  I edited my answer to clarify.